# How come my text is not centering on the mobile version

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, center

I'm new to programming and I am trying to make a responsive web page. The text is centered on the desktop version, but on the mobile version, for some reason the text is aligned to the right and I cannot figure out how to make it perfectly in the middle. Could someone please look at my code and tell me what I am doing wrong? Thank you!

```css
*{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif;
}
.header{
        min-height: 100vh;
        width: 100%;
        background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(4,9,30,0.7),rgba(4,9,30,0.7)),url(assets/banner.png);
        background-position: center;
        background-size: cover;
        position: relative;
}
nav{
    display: flex;
    padding: 2% 6%;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}
nav a{      
        color: #fff;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 14px;
}
nav a:hover{
    color:#f44336;
    transition: .4s;
}
.nav-links{
        flex:1;
        text-align: right;
}
.nav-links ul li{
        list-style: none;
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 8px 12px;
        position: relative;
}
.nav-links ul li a{
        color: #fff;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 13px;
}
nav ul li a:hover{
    color:#f44336;
    transition: .4s;
}
.text-box{
        width: 90%;
        color: #fff;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
        text-align: center;
}
.text-box h1{
    font-size: 54px;
}
.text-box p{
    margin: 10px 0 40px;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #fff;
}

nav .fa{
        display: none;
}

@media(max-width: 700px){
    nav{
        display: flex;
        padding: 4% 8%;
        justify-content: space-between;
        align-items: center;
    }
        .text-box h1{
                font-size: 14px;
        }
        .text-box p{
                font-size: 11px;
        }
        .text-box{
        text-align: center;
        }
        .nav-links ul li {
            display: block;
        }
        .nav-links{
            position: absolute;
            background: #f44336;
            height: 100vh;
            width: 200px;
            top: 0;
            right: -200px;
            text-align: left;
            z-index: 2;
            transition: 1s;
        }
        nav ul li a:hover{
            color:#12161d;
            transition: .4s;
        }
        nav .fa{
            display: block;
            color: #fff;
            margin: 10px;
            font-size: 22px;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
        .nav-links ul{
            padding: 30px;
        }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Personal Homepage</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Noto+Sans:wght@400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free@5.15.4/css/fontawesome.min.css">
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/012219d900.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<style>
.text-box{
background-color: transparent;
color: #FFF;
margin: 20px;
padding: 20px;
}
</style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <section class="header">
            <nav>
                <a href="index.html">AMANDA YEE</a>
                <div class="nav-links" id="navLinks">
                  <i class="fa fa-times" onclick="hideMenu()"></i>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="about.html">ABOUT</a></li>
                        <li><a href="gallery.html">GALLERY</a></li>
                        <li><a href="CV.html">CV</a></li>
                        <li><a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <i class="fa fa-bars" onclick="showMenu()"></i>
            </nav>
            
<div class="text-box">
    <h1>NICE TO MEET YOU</h1>
    <p>Hi! My name is Amanda Yee and I'm a User Experience Designer studying at Pratt.
    </p>
</div>

</section>

<!--Footer-->

<section class="footer">
    <div class="icons">
    <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/amanda-zi-yee/"> <i class="fa fa-linkedin-square"></i></a>
    <a href="https://www.instagram.com/yu.zixin/"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a>
    <a href="mailto:ayee3@pratt.edu"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i></a>
    </div>
</section>






<!--Javascript for Toggle Menu-->
    <script>
        var navLinks = document.getElementById("navLinks");
        
        function showMenu(){
            navLinks.style.right = "0";
        }
        function hideMenu(){
            navLinks.style.right = "-200px";
        }
    </script>
    
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I ran your code using the "Run code snippet" button and the title and the subtitle is indeed centered in the output. Could you please provide more context to your issue, such as browswer with version used?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would include `overflow-x: hidden;` into your HTML document as below. That way, you can't scroll horizontally, which is possible in your mobile version, thus leaving your burgermenu's children visible without actually clicking on it. Keep in mind if you insert it into `*`, you will not be able to scroll horizontally at all. Use it where you see fit :)

```css
*{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif;
        overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

As for your text centering, I would suggest using `flexbox` instead of `position: absolute` for your positioning. Flexbox is super simple to use once you get to know how it works. It is also super good for building responsive websites. `position: absolute` is fine in some cases, but when used incorrectly, it can get messy quickly.
Hope this helps! Let me know if you have questions

```css
.text-box{
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="text-box">
      <h1>NICE TO MEET YOU</h1>
      <p>Hi! My name is Amanda Yee and I'm a User Experience Designer studying at Pratt.
      </p>
    </div>
```